# Grunt: Access Sequence/List Data from External YAML File

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, yaml, grunt-contrib-concat

I am trying to access values from an external YAML file in my Gruntfile using:

```
external = grunt.file.readYAML('_config.yml');
```

The `_config.yml` file has the following example data:

```
computer:
  parts:
    - name: brand1
      type: cpu
    - name: brand2
      type: gpu
    - name: brand3
      type: hd
```

I've been trying to access the multi-level YAML data using `<%= %>` grunt templating to get the different name and type values.

```
module.exports = {
  concat: {
    src: ['htdocs/<%= external.computer.parts['type'] %>/<%= external.computer.parts['name'] %>/*.js'],
    dest: 'htdocs/output.js'
  }
};
```

The main goal has been to concat files from different directories this way into one, but I can't seem to access data from the `_config.yml` file beyond `external.computer.parts`. FYI, the structure of the `_config.yml` file has to remained unchanged.

How do you access a sequence/list with different properties this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below are a couple of solutions to consider. However, firstly let's understand what using [`grunt.file.readYAML()`](https://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.file#grunt.file.readyaml) to parse your `_config.yml` file does. It essentially produces the following object:

```js
{
  computer: {
    parts: [
      {
        name: 'brand1',
        type: 'cpu'
      },
      {
        name: 'brand2',
        type: 'gpu'
      },
      {
        name: 'brand3',
        type: 'hd'
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Note** how the value of `parts` is an array of objects.

---

### Solution 1:

Given that you want to utilize [grunt templates](https://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.template) (i.e. `<%= %>`)  to obtain the different `name` and `type` values, consider configuring your `concat` task in your *Gruntfile.js* as follows:

**Gruntfile.js**

```js
module.exports = function (grunt) {

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');

  grunt.initConfig({
    external: grunt.file.readYAML('_config.yml'),

    concat: {
      dist: {
        options: {
          // ...
        },
        src: [
          'htdocs/<%= external.computer.parts[0].type %>/<%= external.computer.parts[0].name %>/*.js',
          'htdocs/<%= external.computer.parts[1].type %>/<%= external.computer.parts[1].name %>/*.js',
          'htdocs/<%= external.computer.parts[2].type %>/<%= external.computer.parts[2].name %>/*.js'
        ],
        dest: 'htdocs/output.js'
      }
    }
    // ...
  });

  grunt.registerTask('default', [ 'concat' ]);

};
```

**Notes:**

1. The value of the `external` property of the object passed into the [`grunt.initConfig`](https://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#grunt-configuration) method is essentially the aforementioned object, i.e. it's the result of utiizing `grunt.file.readYAML()` to parse your `_config.yml`.
2. The value of the `src` property of the `dist` [target](https://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#task-configuration-and-targets), (which is associated with the `concat` [task](https://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#task-configuration-and-targets)), is an array. Each item of this array is where we utilize the `<% ... %>` notation to reference the parts from your `.yml` file.

   Note how we reference each object in the `external.computer.parts` array by it's index, i.e. `[0]`, `[1]`, `[2]`

   ```js
   'htdocs/<%= external.computer.parts[0].type %>/<%= external.computer.parts[0].name %>/*.js'
                                       ^                                      ^
   ```

---

### Solution 2:

Another way to achieve your requirement is to not utilize grunt templates, i.e. `<% ... %>`, at all. Consider the following solution:

**Gruntfile.js**

```js
module.exports = function (grunt) {

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');

  var external = grunt.file.readYAML('_config.yml');

  grunt.initConfig({
    concat: {
      dist: {
        options: {
          // ...
        },
        src: external.computer.parts.map(function(part) {
          return 'htdocs/' + part.type + '/' + part.name + '/*.js'
        }),
        dest: 'htdocs/output.js'
      }
    }
    // ...
  });

  grunt.registerTask('default', [ 'concat' ]);

};
```

**Notes:**

1. This time we assign the result of parsing your `_config.yml` file to a variable named `external`:

   ```js
   var external = grunt.file.readYAML('_config.yml');
   ```
2. The value of the `src` property is computed by utilizing the [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method. Here we create a new array of [glob patterns](https://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#globbing-patterns).

   ```
   src: external.computer.parts.map(function(part) {
     return 'htdocs/' + part.type + '/' + part.name + '/*.js'
   }),
   ```

---

### Benefits:

One of the key benefits that **Solution 2** has over **Solution 1** is:

If we need to add a new part (`name` and `tyoe`) to `_config.yml`. For example:

```
computer:
  parts:
    - name: brand1
      type: cpu
    - name: brand2
      type: gpu
    - name: brand3
      type: hd
    - name: brand4      <-------
      type: foo         <-------
```

With **Solution 1** we will need to add it to the `src` configuration in the *Gruntfile.js*. For example:

```
src: [
  'htdocs/<%= external.computer.parts[0].type %>/<%= external.computer.parts[0].name %>/*.js',
  'htdocs/<%= external.computer.parts[1].type %>/<%= external.computer.parts[1].name %>/*.js',
  'htdocs/<%= external.computer.parts[2].type %>/<%= external.computer.parts[2].name %>/*.js',

   // Newly added...
  'htdocs/<%= external.computer.parts[3].type %>/<%= external.computer.parts[3].name %>/*.js'
],
```

With **Solution 2** we don't have to change the `src` configuration in the *Gruntfile.js* at all.

---

### Edit:

If you're using a fairly recent version of node.js then you can also refactor **Solution 2** as follows:

**Gruntfile.js**

```js
module.exports = function (grunt) {

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');

  const { computer: { parts } } = grunt.file.readYAML('_config.yml');

  grunt.initConfig({
    concat: {
      dist: {
        options: {
          // ...
        },
        src: parts.map(({ type, name }) => `htdocs/${type}/${name}/*.js`),
        dest: 'htdocs/output.js'
      }
    }
    // ...
  });

  grunt.registerTask('default', [ 'concat' ]);

};
```

<sub>Please ignore StackOverflow's inability to syntax highlight the above example correctly.</sub>

**Notes:**

This refactored version utilizes some ES6 features as follows:

- [Object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) is used to unpack the `parts` property/value from the parsed `_config.yml`, into a `parts` variable:

  ```js
  var { computer: { parts } } = grunt.file.readYAML('_config.yml');
  ```
- The value of the `src` property is computed using an [Arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) with the `map()` method, and [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) are used instead of the plus operator (`+`) for string concatenation.

  ```js
  src: parts.map(({ type, name }) => `htdocs/${type}/${name}/*.js`),
  ```

Comment: thanks! tried both solutions and got both of them to work, but **Solution 2** was definitely the more scalable one.