# Grunt concat files into their respective source directory

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, yaml, grunt-contrib-concat

This is a follow-up to a previous question that was [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61400150/grunt-access-sequence-list-data-from-external-yaml-file/61414578). Please refer to that question for added context.

For this question, let's say that my `_config.yml` now looked like this instead:

```
computer:
  parts:
    - name: brand1
      type: cpu
        foo: foo
        bar: bar
        baz: baz
    - name: brand2
      type: gpu
        foo: foo
        bar: bar
        baz: baz
    - name: brand3
      type: hd
        foo: foo
        bar: bar
        baz: baz
```

<sup>*Please ignore `type` for now</sup>

Which is parsed to create a directory tree that looks like this:

```
htdocs/
└── computer/
    └── parts/
        ├── brand1/
        │   ├── foo/
        │   │   └── foo.js
        │   ├── bar/
        │   │   └── bar.js
        │   └── baz/
        │       └── baz.js
        ├── brand2/
        │   ├── foo/
        │   │   └── foo.js
        │   ├── bar/
        │   │   └── bar.js
        │   └── baz/
        │       └── baz.js
        └── brand3/
            ├── foo/
            │   └── foo.js
            ├── bar/
            │   └── bar.js
            └── baz/
                └── baz.js
```

---

When you take a look at [RobC's two answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61400150/grunt-access-sequence-list-data-from-external-yaml-file/61414578):

**Gruntfile.js**

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');

  var external = grunt.file.readYAML('_config.yml');

  grunt.initConfig({
    concat: {
      dist: {
        options: {
          // ...
        },
        src: external.computer.parts.map(function(part) {
          return 'htdocs/' + part.name + '/**/*.js'
        }),
        dest: 'htdocs/output.js'
      }
    }
    // ...
  });

  grunt.registerTask('default', [ 'concat' ]);

};
```

--- AND ---

**Gruntfile.js** (ES6 Version)

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');

  const { computer: { parts } } = grunt.file.readYAML('_config.yml');

  grunt.initConfig({
    concat: {
      dist: {
        options: {
          // ...
        },
        src: parts.map(({ name }) => `htdocs/${name}/**/*.js`),
        dest: 'htdocs/output.js'
      }
    }
    // ...
  });

  grunt.registerTask('default', [ 'concat' ]);

};
```

both achieve the task of concatenating all files from every directory + subdirectory into one `htdocs/output.js`, but what I would like to know in this problem is: **How can I setup my Gruntfile so that once `grunt concat` is run, Grunt would concatenate files in one array index into the root of its source, while looping through every index in that array**?

---

The directory tree would ideally look something like this after running `grunt concat`:

```
htdocs/
└── computer/
    └── parts/
        ├── brand1/
        │   ├── foo/
        │   │   └── foo.js
        │   ├── bar/
        │   │   └── bar.js
        │   ├── baz/
        │   │   └── baz.js
        │   └── output.js
        ├── brand2/
        │   ├── foo/
        │   │   └── foo.js
        │   ├── bar/
        │   │   └── bar.js
        │   ├── baz/
        │   │   └── baz.js
        │   └── output.js
        └── brand3/
            ├── foo/
            │   └── foo.js
            ├── bar/
            │   └── bar.js
            ├── baz/
            │   └── baz.js
            └── output.js
```

`foo.js`,`bar.js`, and `baz.js` would be concatenated into an `output.js` file and its destination would be: `htdocs/computer/parts/brand1/output.js`, etc...

Comment: Your given `_config.yml` is currently not valid YAML so grunt fails to parse it. You can validate your `_config.yml` online [here](https://yamlvalidator.com/). I suggest you try to fix that then [update/edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61901466/edit) your question. Also you say _"Please ignore `type` for now"_ - so should we delete that from the `.yml` file?

Comment: **Tip:** When re-designing/restructuring your `_config.yml` to be valid YAML, if you're unsure how it will be parsed by grunt, (i.e. what will become an Array, an Object, a property/key name, a value, etc), I suggest you add `console.log(JSON.stringify(external, null, 2));` on the next line after `var external = grunt.file.readYAML('_config.yml');` - This will print the parsed `.yml` to your console and show you the resultant data structure. As previously mentioned currently your `_config.yml` is invalid, therefore it's difficult to understand what it's actual intent is.